# How to compute a managed pointer to the evaluation stack according to ECMA-CIL?

Tags: .net, clr, bytecode, cil, ecma

ECMA-CIL says the following:

> In order to allow managed pointers to be used more flexibly, they are
> also permitted to point to areas that aren‘t under the control of the
> CLI garbage collector, such as the evaluation stack, static variables,
> and unmanaged memory. This allows them to be used in many of the same
> ways that unmanaged pointers (U) are used. Verification restrictions
> guarantee that, if all code is verifiable, a managed pointer to a
> value on the evaluation stack doesn‘t outlast the life of the location
> to which it points.

The text above implies that it is possible to have a managed pointer pointing to the evaluation stack. What instruction does this? The closest I can think of is getting a managed pointer to a local variable, but this is not the evaluation stack.

Comment: It is incomplete, chapter III.1.1.5.2 improves it.  The language is woolly because "the stack" is an implementation detail.  So yes, pointer to local variable is fine, or to a method argument, ldloca or ldarga instruction.  You'd use the & operator in a language like C#.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Just to be on the same page, do you agree that there is no instruction capable of generating a managed pointer to the evaluation stack (a stack slot)? Regardless of its implementation, the evaluation stack is not a local/arg variable. I've just read section "I.12.1.6.1 Homes for values" which does not include the evaluation stack. I think they shouldn't have written "evaluation stack" in the quote from my original post.

Comment: Another data point: _Expert .NET 2.0 IL Assembler_ (Serge Lidin) doesn't list evaluation stack slots as possible things for managed pointers to refer to. "Managed pointers are always references to an item in existence--a field, an array element, a local variable, or a method argument." (p148).

Comment: Managed pointer can also point to memory allocated by `localloc` which is on stack, though specification says it's in *local memory pool*. Specification have some errors, for example it says that managed pointer cannot be `null` in II.14.4.2, although it can; II.9.4 states that byref cannot be used as method return type, although it can

Comment: @JL0PD A managed pointer can be null because a local variable containing a managed pointer type must have a default value. Is it what you meant? Is there any other case involving null managed pointers?

Comment: @ManuelCarrasco, yes, and also unmanaged pointer (which can have null value) can be passed as managed pointer. There are API that works with null managed pointers, for example System.Runtime.InteropServices or System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.IsNullRef

Comment: Thanks, @JL0PD! Very valuable insight.